# Timeseries interpolation of 3D Volume (MATLAB or Python)

Tags: python, matlab, 3d, volume, interpolation

I was wondering what methods or techniques are available when interpolating between 3D volumes over time.

Say I have `V1 (x,y,z t1, coordinates)`, and `V2 (x,y,z,t2)`. I want to basically have a smooth transition over time when I visualize this data in Paraview (or any 3D visualization). What's the best way to interpolate between `V1`, and `V2`?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done fairly simply in MATLAB using the time series resample command

First create a [timeseries object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseriesclass.html):

```
ts1=timeseries([x, y, z],t);
```

Then use the [resample command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html) to interpolate data to a new time series `t2`:

```
ts2 = resample(ts, t2);
```

The data is now accessible in `ts2.data`